# Is it possible to hack a single computer without injecting a payload or a virus?

Tags: network, metasploit

I know the ways to hack a computer or a mobile phone by injecting payload using some exploits with metasploit. We can inject a exe, or we can use pdf file, or docx file as I know.

I wonder the possible attack types for any operating systems without injecting any payload, to just directly connect the machine.

Comment: "hack" is a broad term. If you can define what you mean by that, then the different options become apparent.

Comment: Well , I meant remote access to the computer without permission so that I can run every command on the remote machine , like we do by using metasploit or armitage .

Comment: I think OP baited a lot of replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's entirely possible to hack a system without malware, you can do this by taking advantage of vulnerabilities in applications/OSs or poor configurations. Some great examples (some historic) are:

- Default passwords: there are still routers on the internet with the default password cisco (or no password at all), or servers with system/system, root/toor, etc, or guest accounts with high privileges
- Bad coding allowing crafted IP packets to exploit buffer overflows, unsanitized inputs or other flaws to execute commands (creating accounts, escalating privileges, etc). An old favorite (long since patched) of mine is the [Ping of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_of_death), where a single ping could bring down a system
- Mis-using physical access: booting to single user mode, or plugging into a serial port on a network device

Most malware simply automates the process of using these flaws, you can still do it manually.

Comment: Not sure I agree with parts of this answer. **1)** `Buffer overflows` require a "payload" to properly exploit and "hack," which is essentially a potential malware installer in and of itself. **2)** Regarding "unsanitized inputs" (wrong approach, but I understand your meaning), you are *injecting* SQL code; a "payload" that isn't supposed to be there. **3)** Ping of death is not hacking... it will not give you access to a machine unless you ping the firewall offline, and connections continue as if they didn't care.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo, some of this depends on semantics and how you define hacking and payload. To me hacking includes denial of service as you are getting a system to do something unintended, even if doesn't give you access. I'm using payload in the context of the question, where a payload is a file, but I agree payload could just be the contents of a single packet.

Comment: I think the root problem is that the question is unclear.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Set up a SSH server with a weak root password, and leave it on the internet - within a few hours, you'll have been hacked. They will probably then upload a payload of some sort, but could just as easily pull the data from the machine with the existing software stack.

Essentially, the key would be exploiting some form of authentication flaw, or dealing with a bug in a pre-installed piece of software. These are relatively uncommon nowadays, but they were more common with things such as the R tools, which tended to rely on what the client machine reported to verify access permissions.

Comment: thank you. I want to ask , how do the attacks work on a single personal computer?

Answer (score 4):

It's called a remote code execution vulnerability and Windows had several of these in the past which were exploited quite widely. A good example is the [Win32.Blaster worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaster_%28computer_worm%29) from 2003 which propagated automatically by exploiting a weakness in Windows DCOM RPC Interface.

When the worm was released there already was a patch for the vulnerability available, but back then Windows was far more lenient about auto-applying updates, so many systems were not patched. But in the past 12 years Microsoft drastically improved their update policy, so systems with known vulnerabilities being online is far less frequent today.

But operating systems are not the only applications which can be vulnerable to such exploits. Any software which listens to the Internet can potentially be vulnerable.

Comment: +1 for stating that any software facing public interfaces is potentially vulnerable

Comment: But doesn't remote code execution require the injection of a payload before hacking can occur? The payload being the remote code... Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible there's some confusion here regarding your question. What do you mean by payload injection? Do you mean something that exploits a vulnerability and uses that to inject code?

I'll start with the assumption that you mean injecting code.

---

### Payload Injection and you

It's possible many people here are misunderstanding the term "payload." Technically, even my examples could be considered "payloads" if you want to get into semantics.

However, if you want to assume that no **code injection** is required, then:

- Exploiting `buffer overflows` *is* a form of payload injection.
- `SQL injection` *is* a form of payload injection.
- *Anything* that requires you to **inject code** to exploit it is payload injection.

Read more about [payloads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_%28computing%29).

---

### Is it possible to hack without injecting code?

Here are a few examples which don't require *any* form of `code injection`, as per the assumed requirements of your question.

1. A badly-configured Windows Server that allows double-backslashes to the IP and exposes their drives/resources to the internet. For example: Back in the day, you could simply use `\\192.168.101` (this is a local example; it could be any IP address) to connect to badly-configured servers and do whatever you wanted. Actually, you can still do that to many machines. It's terrible.
2. Default username and password for almost anything critical.
3. Open services that allow remote access when they shouldn't, but which also don't require any form of code injection.